# HTML input pattern

Tags: html

I am using the input pattern on my register form which consists of a Username, Email and Password.

I have set the Username between 5 and 15 characters however when this has been typed correctly and I go to submit the form I am not able to submit, but instead still receive the required title message.  Anyone any ideas?

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9"><td><input pattern=".{5, 15}" required title="Username should be between 5 - 15 characters"type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" placeholder="User Name" required/></td> </div>
```

Comment: Use regular expression like describe here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space before 15: `pattern=".{0,15}"`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern, it works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d11z1a0k/)

```
pattern=".{5,15}$"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the space. Compare the explanations from https://regex101.com/

> ```
>  /.{5, 15}/
> ```
>
> - `.` matches any character (except newline)
> - `{5, 15}` matches the characters {5, 15} literally
>
> and
>
> ```
>  /.{5,15}/
> ```
>
> - `.{5,15}` matches any character (except newline)
> - Quantifier: `{5,15}` Between 5 and 15 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]